# Create JSON Object with Velocity Template Language

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-appsync, vtl, apache-velocity

I am working with the  Apache Velocity Template Language (VTL) in AWS AppSync.
In my request template I query an undefined amount of items with different elements.
What I want to do in the response template is to transform the result into a JSON Object which I need later on for my BatchDeleteItem operation.
This is how I solved it currently:

```
#set($deleteObject='{"Id" : { "S": "nodelete" },"Sk" : { "S": "nodelete" }}')
#set($replaceDeleteObject ="")
#set($separator="")

#foreach( $item in $ctx.result.items )
  #set($replaceDeleteObject = $replaceDeleteObject + $separator + '{"Id" : { "S": "' + $item.Id + '" },"Sk" : { "S": "' + $item.Sk + '" }}')
  #set($separator = ",")
  #set($deleteObject = $replaceDeleteObject)
#end

$util.qr($ctx.stash.put("deleteObject", $deleteObject))
```

Later on I can access my deleteObject and it works properly.

**My question however is**, if it is possible to directly create some kind of JSON Object in vtl in which I can append my values instead of creating this string in the form of a JSON Object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can follow this example from the [AppSync Batch docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appsync/latest/devguide/tutorial-dynamodb-batch.html#single-table-batch):

```
#set($ids = [])
#foreach($id in ${ctx.args.ids})
    #set($map = {})
    $util.qr($map.put("id", $util.dynamodb.toString($id)))
    $util.qr($ids.add($map))
#end

{
    "version" : "2018-05-29",
    "operation" : "BatchGetItem",
    "tables" : {
        "Posts": {
            "keys": $util.toJson($ids),
            "consistentRead": true
        }
    }
}
```

So for your case it should look like this:

```
#set ($batchDeleteArray = [])
#foreach( $item in $ctx.result.items )
  #set ($entry = {
    "Id": $util.dynamodb.toString($item.Id),
    "Sk": $util.dynamodb.toString($item.Sk)
  })

  $util.qr($batchDeleteArray.add($entry))
#end

{
    "version" : "2018-05-29",
    "operation" : "BatchDeleteItem",
    "tables" : {
        "TableName": {
          "keys": $util.toJson($batchDeleteArray)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a map/dictionary which is close to JSON object that you need. There is a programming guide [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appsync/latest/devguide/resolver-mapping-template-reference-programming-guide.html) which should have the information you need, but essentially what you want is something like this.

```
#set($deleteObject={
     "Id" : $util.dynamodb.toString("nodelete"),
     "Sk" : $util.dynamodb.toString("nodelete")
})
```

Comment: Unfortunately I have multiple items which would append to an object array. That is not possible with the map/dictonary